# Button click event not working while working with div container

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I have a simple HTML button in my webpage having its HTML shown below:

```html
<div id="submit1" style="float:left;cursor:pointer;" onclick="checkValidity();">
    <input type="button" value="Finish" class="finish">
</div>
```

When I applied the `onclick="checkValidity();"` on my button it was not working but when I tried it with the container div of the input button it starts working.

I am unable to understand why it was not working while I called this function in button? Can anyone have any idea on it.

Interesting thing is that is working in another webpage on the input button too... !

Answer (score 0):

First of all, checkValidity is a keyword. Stop using it. Change it to CheckIfValid or something like that.

Simple example in the jsfiddle. [Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjyu6b5e/)

```
chck = function (obj)
{
    alert('hi: ' + obj.id);
    return true;
}
```

checkValidity is an event for input objects and returns true if the input has valid data. So, there is no scope for js event here.

It works on div because DIV is not an input element.

Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score -2):

You have to surround that input tag inside a form tag.

```
<div id="submit1" style="float:left;cursor:pointer;" onclick="checkValidity();">
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="Finish" class="finish">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The op said that if he puts the `<input>` inside the `<div>` then it works. Your answer is nonsense.

Comment: He said when he put the event on the div surrounding the input tag, you didn't understand nothing so don't give negative votes randomly ¬¬

Comment: checkValidity is an inbuilt event in javascript. It throws true/false based on input element's data. So, the main issue is using the wrong function name on input elements. checkValidity works on div as its not a input element.